# Div not working in Wordpress post

Tags: html

I have a fresh installation of Wordpress and when writing a post I am trying to surround the paragraphs between some div tags, so that I can add a border to them with CSS.

However, each time I publish the post or I switch to the visual editor (I am not using Guttenberg) some line breaks are missing.

This is what I want to get:

```
Paragraph

<div class="myclass">Paragraph

Paragraph</div>

Paragraph
```

But I get random changes like:

```
Paragraph

<div class="myclass">Paragraph
Paragraph</div>

Paragraph
```

Is this possible? Or should I use something different than the div element?

Answer (score 0):

End-of-line has no meaning in HTML, except if it separates text,
where it is taken as one blank.

If Wordpress is eliminating blank lines, it's only optimizing your code.

To add a blank line, use the
[HTML br Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp):

```
<br>
```

Or the more syntactically correct (but equivalent):

```
<br/>
```

Comment: Please stop answering off-topic posts. It's not the first time I've asked you. It only encourages **more** off topicposts.

Comment: But the code editor of Wordpress doesn't show <br />. It's a mixture of html. Can I get the best of my knowledge of html (to add the div element) together with the visual editor of Wordpress so that I can keep writing articles easily?